# Disable Glassfish 4.1 connection keep-alive

Tags: java, glassfish

How can the connection keep-alive be disabled for glassfish 4.1.

Meaning: clients connecting to my glassfish http port won't be allowed to keep their connections alive.

According to the migration manual, the configuration key for that changed from glassfish 3.0 to glassfish 4.0 but I can't figure out the new configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm not sure why you want to do this, keep-alive is not enabled by default in Glassfish 4. Maybe you have something in front of it like Apache, which is adding the keep-alive header?**

According to the [Glassfish 4 Migration Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/upgrade-guide.pdf), the element was moved from

```
server-config.http-service.keep-alive.timeout-in-seconds
```

to

```
server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.timeout-seconds
```

But changing this setting doesn't have any effect for me, I can't get Glassfish to send the keep-alive header, this would be very weird if you had the opposite problem.

Comment: Can you say for sure that GF 4 actually never uses keep-alive or is it just that changing the setting doesn't affect the keep-alive timeout? I'm currently struggling with getting an Apache HttpClient as proxy for a GF 4 backend working, which is using a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`, i.e. a pool implementation that tries to keep connections open after the client returned them to the pool. And then there's an [open issue for Payara](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1141) that seems to confirm that keep-alive is indeed simply broken.

Comment: I only can say that it didn't affect the keep-alive timeout in my case. But I would not expect that Glassfish sets the header in some cases and in some cases not.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my question: so we know that GF never sends the Keep-Alive header. But do you know if the connections _are_ actually closed right after having served the request or are they still open for some (indetermined? or the default of 30s?) time?

Comment: I went ahead and tested it for myself: The setting of "timeout-seconds" _is_ respected by Payara 4.1.1.164. The default value of 30s means that if I send two requests through Apache HttpClient using a connection pool that reuses persistent connections, the second request still receives a response if it's sent within 30s or less, but fails with `NoHttpResponseException` if it's sent after 31s. And an explicit (lower) timeout value is also applied.

Comment: The behaviour for a value of "0" seems to be wrong though, the connection is closed immediately. According to https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21009, it should be kept open indefinitely, and that's supposed to be fixed. As a reminder, this is all with the latest Payara, so GF bugfixes *should* all be included.

Comment: I verified all that I wrote before for GF 4.1, too. (not tested with 4.1.1)